# How do I get a light to effect one object in a scene and yet not another when I have several lights?

Tags: rendering, lighting

I have a light in my scene and I want it to effect 1 object, but not another. Is there a setting I can turn on/off for this result?        I'm not talking about how to turn off the object's visibility to light because there is more than one light in the scene and I want one of the lights to be effecting it while another doesn't.
P.S. I've tried to use different render layers but I need them to be in the same render layer because of light bounces and stuff so I can't have them in different render layers.

Comment: Play with emission pass I guess

Comment: Upload blend file